# How to exponentiation with while loop

Tags: c++

I've a trouble. Like in descripton. How to do it in c++? Teacher gave a exercise that we must use three loops (for, **while** adn do..while), and this while loop is strange for me, what I have wrong in this code?

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
int a, b, c, d;
cin >> a;
cin >> b;
c = a;
d = 1;
while(b < 1){
    c*=a;
}

if(b == 0)
    cout << d;

else
    cout << c;

return 0;
}
```

result of the action is equal `a`.

Comment: In `while(b < 1){
    c*=a;
}`, where do you change the value of `b`?  If you don't change `b`, the condition will always be the same

Comment: "How to exponentiation" --> [std::pow](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/pow).

Comment: @JesperJuhl I can't use a pow, only loops

Comment: Is the idea to calculate a^b with a while loop?

Comment: @NathanOliver change a instruction on: `while(b < 1){c*=a; b--; }` and still result is `a` ;/

Comment: You shouldn't do `b--` if your condition is `b < 1`.

Comment: @ChrisD my stupid teacher told us to make this exponentiation by these 3 loops

Comment: @SombreroChicken so, what I should to do?

Comment: From you question it seems you know how to write it with a `for` loop. So if you have `for(A;B;C) {X}`, this becomes `A while(B) {X C}`, where A,B,C, and X is any code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are looking for this answer.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int a, b, c, d;
    cin >> a;
    cin >> b;
    c = a;

    if(b == 0)  {
        cout << 1 << endl;
        return 0;
    }

    while(b>1) {
        c *= a;
        b--;
    }

    cout << c;

    return 0;
}
```

In your code you haven't reduced the value of b. Again your condition in while loop is not right. See this solution. I hope you can understand it. If not please mention in comments. Happy coding.

Comment: yeah, that's it. Thanks man :D. ( I wrote b < 1 instead b > 1 haha)

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your question correctly, you want to create a `std::pow()` function of your own using do..while loop. This can be done in the following way:

```
float my_pow(float base, unsigned int exp)
{
    if(exp == 0) return 1;
    else if(exp == 1) return base;

    float result = base;

    do
    {
        result *= base;
        --exp;
    }
    while(exp > 1)

    return result;
}
```